# Mysql : Write Trigger on value of a table column and update same and another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Topic table: id, name, duedate, starttime, duration, status

I need to change the status of this table to completed when 
 starttime + duration reaches current time.
In case, status is updated, I need to change another column status as complete too.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. SO is **not** a code writing service.

Comment: I need to know is this possible in Mysql. Will trigger be the best solution. I am not able to understand how can i use triggers based on column value related to current time.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to change the status of this table to completed when starttime + duration reaches current time.

No, trigger function can't support this. As an alternative, you can create a background application that runs a thread which will update your Topic table periodically, say every minute. 
You can use this SQL statement in you background app or "service":

```
update Topic set status = 'completed' where (starttime+duration)<=now() and not status = 'completed';
```

> In case, status is updated, I need to change another column status as
>   complete too.

This one can be supported using the trigger function if I didn't understand it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. If I am doing one of the task using the code and not by triggers, then it will be better I do all the tasks using the code.

Comment: I recommend to use the trigger function as much as possible if it is applicable because it is way more convenient especially during debugging.